# New to this and trying to incorporate beacons and sound Getting Everything after Return will not be executed

Tags: audio, beacon, region

I am using beacons in this code and want to have regions that are identified by different colors and messages. In the closest region to the beacon, I want the screen to turn red, have a message of you are too close to me and play an alarm sound. The color and message work, but the sound is never played. Here is my code, it must be my use of the word let in the "Danger too close to me" section that causes it to not execute anything after it, but what do I change the let to?

```
import Combine
import CoreLocation
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class BeaconDetector: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var lastDistance = CLProximity.unknown
    var alarm: AVAudioPlayer?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
        didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for:CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }

        func startScanning() {
            let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")!
            let constraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid)
            let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: constraint, identifier: "MyBeacon")

            locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
            locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: constraint)
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {
            if let beacon = beacons.first {
                update(distance: beacon.proximity)
            } else {
                update(distance: .unknown)
            }
        }

        func update(distance: CLProximity) {
            lastDistance = distance
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
}
    struct BigText: ViewModifier {
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
            .font(Font.system(size: 72, design: .rounded))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
}

    struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var detector = BeaconDetector()

    var body: some View {
        if detector.lastDistance == .immediate {
        return Text("DANGER TOO CLOSE TO ME")
             .modifier(BigText())
             .background(Color.red)
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

        let sndurl = Bundle.main.url (forResource: "Alarm", withExtension: "mp3")!
        var snd : SystemSoundID = 0
         AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(sndurl as CFURL, &snd)
         AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion (snd) { AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(snd) }
        }

        else if detector.lastDistance == .near {
        return Text("Outer Zone")
             .modifier(BigText())
             .background(Color.orange)
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else if detector.lastDistance == .far {
        return Text("Far")
             .modifier(BigText())
             .background(Color.yellow)
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else {
        return Text("UNKNOWN")
            .modifier(BigText())
            .background(Color.green)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)


    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement causes execution of the method of subroutine to halt.  Execution then resumes with whoever called that method, and the value after the `return` statement (in this case a `Text` object) is made available to the caller.

To fix the specific problem you ask about, simply move the code where you play the sound above the `return` statement so it actually executes.